# UpdateAttribute for Created_at, but where can i find created_at?

Tags: attributes, magento-1

I have an extension with this installer script

```
$prodEntityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$installer->updateAttribute($prodEntityTypeId, 'created_at', 'frontend_label', 'Date');
$installer->updateAttribute($prodEntityTypeId, 'created_at', 'used_for_sort_by', 1);
```

The about script seems to make `created_at` attribute to be `used_for_sort_by`, but

1. where is the created_at attribute?
2. does this attribute exist in a fresh magento install?

I can't find in magento backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `created_at` is created when you [install magento](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L828).
You can find it in the table `eav_attribute`.
You can isolate it using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE 
    attribute_code = 'created_at' AND
    entity_type_id = (
        SELECT entity_type_id 
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
    )
```

You cannot see it in the backend because it is marked as [not visible](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L833) when installing it